# I got this error There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

**Do i need to install hive in order to use sqoop on my machine?**
while i try to import the data from mysql to hadoop it throws error like this:

```
bhandarisamir@Lomass-MacBook-Pro ~ % sqoop import \
  --connect jdbc:mysql://lord-MacBook-Pro.local:3306/employees \
  --username root \
  --password password \
  --table employees \
  --target-dir /user/hadoop/employees
```

> 23/11/16 23:41:06 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException
> running import job:
> org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File
> /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/bhandari/.staging/job_1700188909100_0001/libjars/mysql-connector-java-5.1.48.jar
> could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).
> There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this
> operation.

I expected the data from mysql to import here http://localhost:50070/explorer.html#/. But it was unsuccessful .

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sqoop requires Hive, but your error says HDFS is not running, so Hive won't work without a healthy HDFS cluster

You need to look at the namenode and datanode logs for connection issues before running any sqoop commands

Note that sqoop itself is a retired Apache project. SparkSQL is often used query jdbc tables instead